# Unable to load dll: Module cannot be found

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2012, path

I am using a managed DLL that referencing an unmanaged dll. 
I added the unmanaged dll under */External/foo/ directory*, and i changed the "Copy To Output Directory" to always.

The problem is that the dlls are copied to the *outputDir/External/foo* dir and when the runtime tries to find it, it fails with this error: *"Unable to load dll: Module cannot be found"*

When i copy it directly to the output dir, everything works well.

How can i set the project runtime to search in the sub directories of the outut dir?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post your code? Thx

Comment: can't you use a postbuild step?

Comment: As mentioned by @rene, add a postbuild step that copies the files in external/foo/ to the output directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Everywhere I go, people tell me to avoid post build events, I know about the option to do the xcopy, but it sounds like opening door to problem. It is weird that i can't direct my project to look into the subdirectories of the output dir. The dlls are there! only two sub directories away! :) I would love to hear if someone knows about a way to do it via the visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do this, DLL Search Hell is something you want to avoid.  Windows is pretty inflexible about where it looks for DLLs.  Rightfully so, DLL Hell is nothing to mess with.  The only good place for unmanaged DLLs is in the same directory as your EXE.  If you don't want to store the DLLs in the project directory, so copying them is very easy, then you are going to need a post-build event that uses xcopy.exe to copy the DLL to the output directory.

The alternatives are *not* pretty.  If this DLL is implicitly loaded then the only option is to use an installer to add the directory to the system's PATH environment variable.  This is a Really Bad idea, way too easy for your program to break.  If it is loaded explicitly, either with LoadLibrary or a pinvoke declaration then you have more attractive options since you can alter the search path in your Main() method before the DLL is needed.  Either append the path to your local copy of the PATH environment variable by using Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable() or pinvoke SetDllDirectory().  Do beware that you have a deployment problem as well, somebody is going to have to create this subdirectory and copy the DLL there on the user's machine.  All great reasons to **not** do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is something we did in our last project. Write a batch file which copies this unmanaged dll to the output directory. Call the batch file every time the program compiles. You can control the calling of batch file also using a Config key. So it runs based on the config key value true/false. i hope this helps